# How to handle file downloads in headless using watir-webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using headless watir-webdriver and I know that a particular action, browser.div.click prompts a file download. I know when you're using FF, you can specify a folder to download the file into but how can I handle a file download in headless? Is there a way to specify a folder, or better yet read it into memory?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow, that's a tough one. I may try to look at it later. But instinct tells me it's a test to skip for automation.

Comment: I'm actually not doing it for testing purposes but to fetch information from a site written in javascript. I know watir was built for tests, but I was looking for a way to interact with javascript sites. Mechanize doesn't have that functionality and I wasn't able to find any other options.

Comment: Then try doing it with a browser. If that's not going to work, try a professional scraping tool. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is practical to test headless.   how could anything headless prompt the user? I'd think you'd have to tell it where to send the file.  This might be more of a question for the webdriver folks, that's their underlying functionality.  You might just have to call it directly.

does the site implement a REST interface or a way to just get the file directly?  Maybe try cURL or REST-CLient?

If the main purpose is just to download the file, then your first challenge is to see if you can figure out what the URL of the file is from the webpage code.  If you can determine that, then have a look at the cURL gem you could use it (or just cURL from the command line) to invoke a get against the HTTP address for the file download, then save it to a file or work with it in memory as needed

Comment: the site doesn't implement a way to get the file directly, no. Basically, I click a div and I get prompted to download the file (if I'm using a browser)

Comment: @shig  what is the html for the div?  I don't think you are perhaps understanding very well how file transfers over http work.  the prompt for saving comes from the browser.

Comment: perhaps I'm not understanding how file transfers work, in which case I'd love any further information you can give me. If I do something like browser.div(:id, "download-file").click, that prompts the browser download if I'm using a browser but ideally I'd like to do this headless. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok so to start with, show us the HTTP for that div, or better yet a URL for the page if it's up somewhere we can see it.  Div tags are not inherently 'clickable' like a link would be, so there has to be client side code there (usually javascript) that is reacting to something like an onclick event.  At some point that code is having the client request the file from the webserver, when the browser see's the response from the server, and can tell it's a file being transferred (not just part of the web page) the browser prompts the user for what to do with the file.

Comment: A 'headless' browser has no way to do that prompting, since there is no UI and no true way to interact with a human.  Can you figure out what the URL of the file is and just download it directly using HTTP functions or the CURL gem?

Comment: There is no file URL. Also, it's behind a log in but I could provide you with a login if you'd like (just PM me). The HTTP is a POST with a cookie that includes various dynamic parameters and tokens (making reconstructing these cookie parameters very difficult). The response headers has something like Content-disposition: attachment; filename=fname.ext, and as I understand it, this header raises the File Download dialog box.

Comment: guess there is no PMing on SO. I can be contacted at odaniinteractive.com

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be to change the profile settings to display the binary content in the browser instead of opening a download dialog.